# gui fail to boot after dist-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, upgrade

I just ran apt-get dist-upgrade from 14.04.2 and it upgraded ubuntu to 14.04.3. But when i rebooted my laptop my gui wont boot. I tried purging the nvidia drivers (sudo apt-get purge nvidia*) and reinstall (sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings) but with no luck.

Any ideas why my drivers would start to fail after dist-upgrade?

EDIT: I noticed that if I let my laptop go to sleep and then waking it up the GUI boots correctly with nvidia-346 drivers so it seems the drivers work but something isnt booting correctly. Any ideas what?

I have a gefore gtx 860M (also intel 4400).

Comment: What do you mean by upgrading from 12.04.2 to 12.04.3? How you did that?

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade which I think changed my ubuntu version from 14.04.2 to 14.04.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install wrong Nvidia drivers.

`nvidia-current` installs legacy drivers that do not support your adapter.

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately still gives me black screen. Any other idea?

Comment: Did the drivers install without errors?

Comment: Yes no errors in the install